# Laravel Stripe Setup

Tags: php, laravel

okay, this is my first time to ask a question here so please give grace if it's not very clear. Anyway, I have this code in Laravel Billing.php.

Is this correct? Whenever a new customer is created, it doesn't have it's user email address but instead this unknown@domain.com was assigned to the user.

This was set by my previous developer. But ever since we hired him for just simple fix, we've had numerous issues with the site.

```
$stripeCustomer = StripeCustomer::create([
                    'email' => $currentCustomer->email ? $currentCustomer->email : 'unknown@domain.com',
                    'description' => $company->name,
                    'metadata' => [
                        'company_id' => $company->id,
                        'card_owner_email' => $currentCustomer->email ? $currentCustomer->email : false,
                        'company_name' => $company->name,
                    ],
                ]);
```

Comment: where is your query for `$currentCustomer`?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove customer email from the StripeCustomer when creating since stripe API said that email field of customer is optional. Here is the reference [link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=php)

Here what you should fix:

```
$customerObject = [
    'description' => $company->name,
    'metadata' => [
        'company_id' => $company->id,
        'company_name' => $company->name,
    ],
];
if ($currentCustomer->email) {
    $customerMetadata["metadata"]["card_owner_email"] = $currentCustomer->email;
    $customerObject["email"] = $currentCustomer->email;
}
$stripeCustomer = StripeCustomer::create($customerObject);
```

Comment: I tried and remove the customer email, but it is still returning the error 
Call to a member function create() on null

Comment: I think you should give me full code or you write a debug to check it yourself.